# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. - can't install breakpoint and singularity

Tags: ruby, bash, rubygems, installation

I installed compass and sass and everything worked correctly. But now I am trying to install singularity and breakpoint and I am getting this error over and over:

Sayras-iMac:~ sayralopez$ sudo gem install breakpoint
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing breakpoint:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.9.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/extensions/universal-darwin-12/1.8/ffi-1.9.3/gem_make.out

I am still a newb at terminal commands, so I have no idea what is going on. I tried reinstalling and updating ruby and it still wont work. Any idea what could be going on and how to fix it?

MANY THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Install Ruby Version Manager first:

```
$ ruby install rvm
```

After installing rvm, I was able to install breakpoint and sigularity (and susy!)
Hope that helps!